# Seeking national (USA) interstate rest stop/rest area dataset

Tags: google-maps, mobile, data, point-of-interest

Does a national(USA) interstate rest stop/rest area dataset exist?

I don't care about format because I can worry about that later. I found some maps in Google maps, usually per state.  I also have one map made my someone else, that no longer appears in the Google Maps search for user content.  Maybe that user made it private, but I still can see it.

The reason I ask is related to my [google maps navigation question on android.se](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/is-there-a-way-to-display-interstate-rest-areas-on-google-maps-navigation).  I think the easiest way to get this info on the droid is to create or use a shared map in Google Maps.  I can find Florida, but no others show up.  Maybe it's a vocabulary issue or that rest stops are called something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're going to have to hunt this down on a state-by-state basis. A good place to start is the state spatial data clearinghouses. Google "spatial data clearinghouse" and most states will show up. Unfortunately some states (like my home state) are years behind in things like GIS, so you may not find universal coverage.

Have you seen the mashup at [Programmable Web](http://www.programmableweb.com/mashup/us-rest-areas)? There's a contact page and you might be able to find out where they got the data they used. Doesn't look like the mashup works right now, though.

Another place to check is a page MIT has of spatial data sites at [Online spatial data by state.](http://libraries.mit.edu/gis/data/datalinks/statedataweb.html)

This won't help but I thought it was funny that someone did this: [web site listing rest areas by highway and exit number.](http://www.interstaterestareas.com/)

If you are open to purchasing data, there's NAVTEQ and Tele Atlas, but I think you can probably access most of their data through some map service somewhere.

I haven't used a POI file before, but you can get one at [POI directory.](http://poidirectory.com/poifiles/united_states/transportation/Rest_area-US.html#Points_of_interest)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.poi-factory.com/node/5942 has many rest areas (in .csv or gpx formats)
You will have to check data consistency and merge all for usa coverage.
Also check on copyright of the data for re-distrubution of content.

Answer (score 1):

I created this data set in 2017, but I'm not sure of the exact source. Here is a shared folder with the raw KML data, a python conversion script to put it into CSV for use in Google "My Maps", and the CSV files themselves broken into two groups.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1j3Zke8TID6JG9acO2rOMaKGV9x52HUR3?usp=sharing

[image]