# McDonalds GIS data

Tags: data

Where I can find the GIS coordinates of all the McDonald's restaurants?

Particularly those in New York City?

Further I'd like to [Voronoi tessellate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) the 5 boroughs with respect to these McDonald's locations, bringing new meaning to the idea of "the closest McDonald's".  1st things first.

Comment: The http://www.fastfoodmaps.com/ site in the page I just link to can show all the Maccas in NY.  You might be able to contact the owner for the data.

Comment: A voronoi might not be the best approach for a place like NYC.  The gridded nature of the streets and placement of buildings might mean that it actually takes longer to walk to a McDonalds even if it's within the same voronoi polygon.  Maybe look at some network analysis and use street data.

Comment: ^ most worthwhile and helpful remark i've ever seen across stackex sites -- that actually helps the question reach the essence of the desired goal

Answer (score 2):

Please go to this link [here](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1__LJkwaqdMITekWlhku5Sm64paeTNqD2geyn1no) to download the table with location information for most of McDonald's in NYC.

I actually filtered out those McDonald's data from one CSV table shows all wifi locations in NYC provided by City of New York.

If you wanna check out the original data, you can go to this link [here](https://nycopendata.socrata.com/Media/Wifi-Hotspot-Locations/ehc4-fktp).

Hope it gives you what you are looking for.

Thanks,

Jinnan

Comment: I would encourage you to write a more general answer in the [earlier question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7749/gis-data-for-fast-food-industry) as well, this is an interesting approach!

Comment: You could contact the Department of Public Health for a more empirical dataset, I have recently received all of the restaurants in Los Angeles County in an excel format and made minor changes to plot the data that I needed.  They should have it on file.  Also, try InfoUSA.