# Getting business listing data for mapping for New York?

Tags: data, united-states, address, point-of-interest

How should I go about efficiently compiling the data to map the locations of all the businesses within a given city or town? Are there any free online resources that offer searching businesses by geography and downloading their listings as tabular data which could be geocoded?

At a minimum I would just need the business name and address. The project would be in New York and the business data needs to be mapped in ArcMap.

Comment: Check the [`poi`](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poi) (Point of Interest) tag for related, already-answered questions.

Comment: Also very similar: [GIS data for fast food industry](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7749/gis-data-for-fast-food-industry)